# PineScript : const bool

Tags: constants, pine-script, return-value, pine-script-v5, conditional-operator

Why does this code run:

```
// @version=5
indicator(title="MA 1D", shorttitle="MA 1D", overlay=true) //, timeframe = "60", timeframe_gaps = false )

var Grp_MA = "Using Moving Average on \"close\" source"
int MAlength = input.int(3, minval=1, title="MA Length", group=Grp_MA, inline=Grp_MA)
bool _display_MAlines = input.bool(title = "Display MA 1D lines", defval = false, group=Grp_MA)

float MALine = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", ta.sma(close, MAlength))
plot(MALine, title="MA Line", color=color.rgb(0, 255, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, display= _display_MAlines ? display.pane : display.none )
```

but not this code?

```
// @version=5
indicator(title="MA 1D", shorttitle="MA 1D", overlay=true) //, timeframe = "60", timeframe_gaps = false )

get_parameters() =>
    var Grp_MA = "Using Moving Average on \"close\" source"
    int MAlength = input.int(3, minval=1, title="MA Length", group=Grp_MA, inline=Grp_MA)
    bool _display_MAlines = input.bool(title = "Display MA 1D lines", defval = false, group=Grp_MA)
    [MAlength, _display_MAlines]

[MAlength, _display_MAlines] = get_parameters()
float MALine = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", ta.sma(close, MAlength))
plot(MALine, title="MA Line", color=color.rgb(0, 255, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, display= _display_MAlines ? display.pane : display.none )
```

> Cannot call 'operator ?:' with argument 'expr0'='_display_MAlines'. An argument of 'simple bool' type was used but a 'const bool' is expected.

I can not find the way to fix the 'const bool'.
I tried to used const at different places but it does not seem declared on PineScript,

I also tried different variants like using another bool after the input.bool or before the plot line,

Comment: Try putting the boolean *_display_MAlines* as <list of arguments> of the *get_parameters function*

Comment: It seems that arguments can not be updated into function. It says :
> Function arguments cannot be mutable ('_display_MAlines')
but thanks for trying.